# First Order Ordinary Differential Equation by Any Method (1R-23)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Unsure of direction I should take on this ODE. It is not separable, linear, or exact or can be made exact with a linear factor? Answer in my text is $e^y = ce^x + x^2$. I do not know how they arrived at this answer. Someone please give me a good kick start.

$$e^yy' - e^y = 2x - x^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $e^{y}$ = t and then reduce it to linear first order equation

Comment: @Jules Manson If my answer solves ur problem consider accepting my ans by  clicking on green tick mark thanks

Comment: $@godonichia$ Thank you for the tip but can you please add a little bit more direction? And where is the green tick mark? I am sort of new to these boards.

Comment: When u substitute $e^{y} = t$ u will get $e^{y}dy/dx = dt/dx$ which will become linear first order in t and x .

Comment: Of course now I see it. Thank you for your help.